# Strange IE8 postback issues with ASP.Net form

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have the following form that works as expected in chrome and firefox but in IE on postback the forms values get lost.

An example is the Email textboxes .Text property comes back empty from IE but not FF.

http://www.openawards.org.uk/CalendarEventRegister.aspx?cid=10

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("Select PageTitle from tbContent where Script_Name = 'News.aspx'");
            DataRow dr = Connector.ExecuteDataRow(sql);
            if (dr != null)
                this.Header.Text = dr["PageTitle"].ToString();
            BindMenu();

            PopulateView();
        }
    }
```

Here is an example textbox

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRequiredField" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Name" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
```

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CalendarEventRegister.aspx.cs" Inherits="OCNNWR.CalendarEventRegister" %>

Here is the top of the code behind

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
```

I have never seen this bug before can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some example code showing what is making the postback, and the textboxes in the markup

Comment: Can you show your Page_Load() code?

Comment: Added pageload and textbox markup as requested

Comment: Check if ViewState property in the page directive has been altered from the default?

Comment: Check that EnableViewState property is not set to false in the <%@Page ...%> tag.

Comment: Where is your code for handling the form submission and getting the values from the textbox's?

Answer (score 1):

It truns out there was embedded form tags on the page. Firefox and Chrome seemed to handle it fine but IE didn't like it.